# Error running gatk HaplotypeCaller with allele specific annotations

Tags: variant, gatk

I've got HaplotypeCaller working nicely in standard mode, like so:

```
# Run haplotypcaller
gatk --java-options "-Xmx4g" HaplotypeCaller \
      --intervals "$INTERVALS" \
      -R "$REF" \
      -I "$OUT"/results/alignment/${SN}_sorted_marked_recalibrated.bam \
      -O "$OUT"/results/variants/${SN}_g.vcf.gz \
      -ERC GVCF
```

But when I try in allele-specific mode, I get the following error. All I've done is add the -G annotations at the end, as suggested [here](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360037225632-HaplotypeCaller).

```
# Haplytype caller with allele-specific annotations
gatk --java-options "-Xmx4g" HaplotypeCaller \
      --intervals "$INTERVALS" \
      -R "$REF" \
      -I "$OUT"/results/alignment/${SN}_sorted_marked_recalibrated.bam \
      -O "$OUT"/results/variants/${SN}_g.vcf.gz \
      -ERC GVCF \
      -G Standard \
      -G AS_Standard
```

Here's the error:

```
***********************************************************************

A USER ERROR has occurred: Unrecognized annotation group name: Standard

***********************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that those options should be:
-G StandardAnnotation 
-G AS_StandardAnnotation

At least, when I changed them to that, it didn't throw an error message.

However, I haven't used GATK much, so I'm not sure that's correct. I [posted](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360037225632/comments/7657984397979) on the relevant Broad page, so more info may show up there.